# simple linked list delete fails

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm learning C++, I try to implement simple singly linked list but the delete node part fails. I could not comprehend why this basic delete_node part is failing. It seems prev->set_next line in delete_node method does not working correctly. I tried to debug it too but failed to spot the error.

```
using namespace std; //ignore it for simplicity

class Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node() {}
    void set_data(int a_data)
    {
        data = a_data;
    }
    void set_next(Node *a_next)
    {
        next = a_next;
    }

    int get_data()
    {
        return data;
    }

    Node* get_next()
    {
        return next;
    }
};


class List {
    Node *head;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    void print_list();
    void append_node(int data);
    void delete_node(int data);
};

void List::print_list()
{
    Node *temp = head;
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(temp->get_next() == NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->get_data() << "--->";
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << temp->get_data() << "+++>";
            temp = temp->get_next();
        } while(temp != NULL);
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
}

void List::append_node(int data)
{
    Node *new_node = new Node();
    new_node->set_data(data);
    new_node->set_next(NULL);

    Node *temp = head;
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        while(temp->get_next()!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        temp->set_next(new_node);
    }
    else
    {
        head = new_node;
    }
}


void List::delete_node(int data)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *prev = NULL;
        do
        {
            prev = temp;
            if(temp->get_data() == data)
            {
                prev->set_next(temp->get_next());
                delete temp;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->get_next();
        } while(temp!=NULL);
    }
}


int main()
{
    List list;
    list.append_node(10);
    list.append_node(20);
    list.append_node(30);
    list.append_node(40);
    list.append_node(50);
    list.append_node(60);

    list.delete_node(30); //

    list.print_list();
    return 0;
}
```

valgrind gives me following error.

```
==22232== Invalid read of size 8
==22232==    at 0x400D38: Node::get_next() (20_1.cpp:25)
==22232==    by 0x400A5E: List::print_list() (20_1.cpp:62)
==22232==    by 0x400C6C: main (20_1.cpp:127)
==22232==  Address 0x5abdd28 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==22232==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22232==    by 0x400BA8: List::delete_node(int) (20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that at the beginning of your `do` / `while` loop pointers `temp` and `prev` point to the same `Node`. Hence, you re-point the node, and then delete it right away.

A better approach is to not use `prev` at all. Get `next`, see if its data matches the one being deleted. If it does, "bypass" and delete `next`. Otherwise, move on to the next node until you hit `NULL`:

```
void List::delete_node(int data) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (head->get_data() == data) {
        Node *toDelete = head;
        head = head->get_next();
        delete toDelete;
        return;
    }
    Node *temp = head;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        Node *next = temp->get_next();
        if (next == null) {
            break;
        }
        if (next->get_data() == data) {
            temp->set_next(next->get_next());
            delete next;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->get_next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a closer look at these lines from the `List::delete_node` function

```
prev = temp;
if(temp->get_data() == data)
{
    prev->set_next(temp->get_next());
    delete temp;
    break;
}
```

The first one make `prev` point to the very same node that `temp` is pointing to. After this `prev == temp` is true.

So when you do

```
prev->set_next(temp->get_next());
```

it is the same as

```
temp->set_next(temp->get_next());
```

That is, you make `temp->next` point to `temp->next` which doesn't change it at all. You never unlink the node from the list, but you do delete it. That makes your printing of the list invalid, as you will dereference a deleted node.

As a simple solution, you could do something like this:

```
if (head->get_data() == data)
{
    // Special case: Head node is the one we want to delete
    Node* old_head = head;

    // Make the head be the second node in the list, if any
    head = head->get_next();

    // Delete the old head
    delete old_head;
}
else
{
    // We know it's not the head node of the list, use the "next" to find it
    for (Node* node = head; node->get_next() != 0; node = node->get_next())
    {
        if (node->get_next()->get_data() == data)
        {
            // It's the "next" node we want to remove
            Node* old_next = node->get_next();

            // Unlink the node
            node->set_next(node->get_next()->get_next());

            delete old_next;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact working solution is

```
void List::delete_node(int data)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    //first check whether its a parent element or not 
    if(temp && temp->get_data() == data){
      head = head->get_next();
      delete temp;
    }
    else{
      while (temp){
        if (temp->get_data() == data){
            if (prev)
                prev->set_next(temp->get_next());
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->get_next();
      }
  }
}
```

This even works for deleting head node

Comment: Seriously, what do you mean by altering the head pointer regardless of whether the node being removed is the head node or not. Did you even trace it.?

Comment: You are still not checking for an empty list, at least.

Answer (score -1):

I see a number of problems with your code.

Your `Node` constructors is not initializing any of the `Node` members.

Your `List` class is missing a destructor to free any allocated nodes.

Your `print_list()` and `append_node()` implementations are a little more verbose than they need to be.

But, most importantly, regarding your particular question, your list's `delete_node()` method is not managing its `prev` variable correctly.  `prev` is always pointing at the current node that is being looked at, not at the previous node that was already looked at.  So you are not actually updating your links correctly when removing a node.  You are also not updating the list's `head` member if the node being removed is the `head` node.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Node;

class List {
    Node *head;
public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void print_list();
    void append_node(int data);
    void delete_node(int data);
};

class Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(int a_data = 0, Node *a_next = NULL);

    void set_data(int a_data);
    void set_next(Node *a_next);

    int get_data();
    Node* get_next();

    friend class List;
};
```

```
Node::Node(int a_data, Node *a_next)
    : data(a_data), next(a_next)
{
}

void Node::set_data(int a_data)
{
    data = a_data;
}

void Node::set_next(Node *a_next)
{
    next = a_next;
}

int Node::get_data()
{
    return data;
}

Node* Node::get_next()
{
    return next;
}

List::List()
    : head(NULL)
{
}

List::~List()
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp)
    {
        Node *next = temp->get_next();
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
}

void List::print_list()
{
    Node *temp = head;
    if (!temp)
    {
        cout << "empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        cout << temp->get_data();
        temp = temp->get_next();
        if (!temp) break;
        cout << "+++>";
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "--->NULL" << endl;
}

void List::append_node(int data)
{
    Node **temp = &head;
    while (*temp) temp = &((*temp)->next);
    *temp = new Node(data);
}

void List::delete_node(int data)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *prev = NULL;

    while (temp)
    {
        if (temp->get_data() == data)
        {
            if (prev)
                prev->set_next(temp->get_next());
            if (temp == head)
                head = temp->get_next();
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->get_next();
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    List list;
    list.append_node(10);
    list.append_node(20);
    list.append_node(30);
    list.append_node(40);
    list.append_node(50);
    list.append_node(60);

    list.delete_node(30); //

    list.print_list();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I'm learning CPP, I would like to know about all the problems.

Comment: This solution doesn't work, if you try to delete parent node.

Comment: @Dinesh: [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/xLvtDL). There are no "parent" nodes in this code.

Comment: You made the changes and @RemyLebeau yes, it will work now